# postgresql group two counts

Tags: postgresql, count, sum

I was wondering if there is anyway of combining these two counts in the same table, like (Titulo, count1, count2).
First one:

```
select Titulo, count(genero)
from livro natural inner join genero
group by titulo;
```

Output:

```
    titulo                       count
1   A lei                          2
2   Olhar misterioso               2
3   Pensamento ao anoitecer        2
4   Ajudar e proteger              2
5   A corrupcao                    2
6   O crime do seculo              2
7   Sem volta                      2
8   Andar protegido                2
9   A bem ou mal                   2
10  Diarios de um policia          2
```

Second one:

```
select Titulo, count(IDMemb)
from genero natural inner join livro natural inner join gosta 
group by titulo;
```

Output:

```
titulo                          count
1   A lei                         6
2   Olhar misterioso              4
3   Pensamento ao anoitecer.      4
4   Ajudar e proteger             4
5   A corrupcao                   6
6   O crime do seculo             6
7   Sem volta                     4
8   Andar protegido               4
9   A bem ou mal                  4
10  Diarios de um policia         4
```

Desired output:

```
titulo                           count.           count
    1   A lei                          2                6
    2   Olhar misterioso               2                4
    3   Pensamento ao anoitecer        2                4
    4   Ajudar e proteger              2                4
    5   A corrupcao                    2                6
    6   O crime do seculo              2                6
    7   Sem volta                      2                4
    8   Andar protegido                2                4
    9   A bem ou mal                   2                4
    10  Diarios de um policia          2                4
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can count only `distinct` genero for second SQL like this

```
select Titulo, count(distinct genero), count(IDMemb)
from genero natural inner join livro natural inner join gosta 
group by titulo;
```